# Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I have a Flutter app with Firebase features, Gradle 7.1.1 and JDK 11.0.12 installed. I had to update to Android Studio Arctic Fox which made have to update Gradle from I think 5.2.4 to 7.1.1. Since then I haven't been able to run the app.

Is there some info I should add for a better diagnosis of the problem?

````
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /Users/SamuelHrmel/Documents/Developer/Flutter/Uniyo/build/firebase_core/generated/ap_generated_sources/debug/out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@384dbb40) before task ':firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported```
````